# behavior explanation for higher order functions and labeled argument in OCaml

Tags: ocaml, higher-order-functions, named

Taking an exemple derived from RWOCaml :

```
utop # let divide ~first ~second = first / second;;
val divide : first:int -> second:int -> int = <fun>

utop # let apply_to_tuple_3 f (first,second) = f second first;;
val apply_to_tuple_3 : ('a -> 'b -> 'c) -> 'b * 'a -> 'c = <fun>

utop # apply_to_tuple_3 divide;;
Error: This expression has type first:int -> second:int -> int
       but an expression was expected of type 'a -> 'b -> 'c
```

Does it make sense to not match the types here ?
`apply_to_tuple_3` only makes use of the positional arguments, which certainly `divide` possesses.

Upon removing the names, the application is accepted

```
utop # let divide_an x y = divide x y;;
val divide_an : int -> int -> int = <fun>
utop # apply_to_tuple_3 divide_an;;
- : int * int -> int = <fun>
```

Is there any reason to reject the first call ?

Answer (score 1):

Functions with labeled parameters have a type that depends on the labels and on the order that they appear. When calling such functions, there is flexibility in the order of arguments that you supply. And in fact you can omit the labels if you supply all of the arguments.

However, when passing such functions as values themselves, there is no such flexibility. You have only the one labeled type to work with.

This is covered on page 42 of Real World OCaml: **Higher-order functions and labels**.

(If you're asking *why* this is the case, I can only assume that type checking becomes difficult or impossible if you allow such flexibility.)

Comment: I am asking why *in this specific case*, where the client does not require names to be present

Comment: The types aren't compatible. A type with labels is not compatible with a type with no labels. The compiler is willing to be flexible when you're calling a function with labelled parameters but not in other cases. You have one of those other cases.

Comment: the type checker deems them incompatible. reason says they are compatible, unless I am missing something. It can be that there are no reason for this different beside the fact that the type checker is simply to rough in that case, which means we do some manual wrapping. That is perfectly fine. I just wonder if there are any real reason which I might have missed.

Comment: No reason. Just a limitation of the type checker and language implementation.

Comment: The two types in question are clearly not equivalent. I.e., one of them is more specific than the other (and not in a parametrically polymorphic way). What you want, I think, is a kind of subtyping. OCaml doesn't infer subtypes, so you would have to annotate the subtyping by hand. I suspect this might work if somebody wanted to put in the work on the type system. In the meantime you can write a function that's similar to this annotation: `let annotate f first second = f ~first ~second`