# Typing in Format with printers with optional arguments

Tags: types, format, arguments, ocaml, option-type

I am facing an interesting behavior of the OCaml typer. The typer seems to fail to accept printer with optional arguments.

When a function has optional arguments, it can be typed as a function with no optional arguments.

```
(** Simple example *)
let (f1 : ?arg : int -> unit -> int) =
  fun ?(arg = 3) () : int -> arg + 5

let f2  : ((unit -> int) -> int) =
  fun f -> f ()

let x : int = f2 f1
(* The type of f1 matches the signature of f2 :
   the optional argument is well discarded. *)
```

Here, `f1` has an optional argument but `f2 f1` is well typed. That is because (or at least, that is what I have understood) the signature of the argument of `f2` encompasses type of `f1`. The optional argument is simply discarded.

However, this behavior is rejected in printers, as shown by this example.

```
 (* Data structure *)
type 'a elt = {
  data : int;
  annot : 'a
}

(* Type of printer annotations *)
type 'annot printer = Format.formatter -> 'annot -> unit

(* Default printer prints nothing *)
let (default : 'a printer) = fun fmt _ -> Format.fprintf fmt ""

(* Generic printer for elts *)
let elt_printer
    ?(print_annot : 'a printer = default)
    (fmt : Format.formatter)
    (elt : 'a elt) =
  Format.fprintf fmt "%i(%a)"
    elt.data
    print_annot elt.annot

(* I don't care about printing the annotation *)
let f (elt : _ elt) =
  Format.printf
    "%a"
    elt_printer elt
```

This is what is returned by the compiler for the use of `elt_printer` in the `fprintf̀` call:

```
This expression has type
         ?print_annot:'a printer -> Format.formatter -> 'a elt -> unit
       but an expression was expected of type Format.formatter -> 'b -> unit
```

I believe the typer manages to infer that `'b = 'a elt`, but fails at discarding the optional argument.

I have two questions regarding this behavior:

1. Is it the expected behavior of the typer for the second example?
2. If not, is there a standard syntax forbidding the use of functions with optional arguments ? For example, is there a way to forbid the use of `f1̀` as an argument of `f2` in the first example ?

Thank you in advance.

EDIT:
It is possible to force the typing of `elt_printer` with no optional argument by expliciting its type.

```
let f (elt : _ elt) =
  Format.printf
    "%a"
    (elt_printer : _ printer) elt
```

EDIT 2: 
For labeled arguments, the typer strictly blocks typing conversions as the arguments must be provided with a specific name. This is not the issue raised in my question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [behavior explanation for higher order functions and labeled argument in OCaml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53132410/behavior-explanation-for-higher-order-functions-and-labeled-argument-in-ocaml)

Comment: My question treats of the difference between two different behaviours for a similar use of high order functions with optional arguments. This thread (though interesting) does not provide a clear answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Yes, this is expected, a function `?foo -> bar -> baz` can not be converted to a function of `bar -> baz`. It can only be applied without the `foo`, which is very different from an implicit conversion
2. There are two solutions

First, you can "not apply" the label: `f ?print_annot:None` will inform the typer that the parameter `print_annot` of `f` should be considered absent.

Secondly, and this is the technique I used for tyxml ([see here](https://ocsigen.org/tyxml/4.3.0/api/Tyxml.Html#2_Printers)), you can add a unit argument:

```
val pp : 
  ?encode:(string -> string) ->
  ?indent:bool ->
  ?advert:string ->
  unit -> 
  Format.formatter -> doc -> unit
```

Then users will have code that looks like this:

```
let s = Format.asprintf "%a" (Tyxml.Html.pp ()) my_html
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I am not sure to understand your point. In my first example, there is an implicit conversion.
Also, I think you are answering the wrong question in the second part. I am not wondering how to define the printer so to match the right signature. I am wondering how to apply the typing restriction used in format arguments in a simpler example (see the first one).